# Можно ли в DTO писать валидацию данных?

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, валидация, dto

Допустим есть входящие данные с клиента и для добавления записи в бд нужно проверить, а все ли данные пришли.

```
const data = {
  login: 'user',
  name: 'Bob',
}

class CreateDTO {
  constructor({login, name}) {
    if (!login) throw Error('Отсутствует Логин');
    if (!name) throw Error('Отсутствует Имя');

    this.login = login;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

const dto = new CreateDTO(data)
// Добавляем объект dto в БД
```

Это нормально так делать или валидацию данных стоит вынести куда то отдельно?

Comment: То что вы сделали, это вообще не нормально ) Создайте функцию и проверяйте данные на их наличие, тип, длину и т.д. на выходе функция скажет true или false

Comment: @SwaD а DTO получается нужен только для того чтобы обрезать объект до нужных параметров?

Comment: Можно и валидировать, только это не должно приводить к ошибке в конструкторе, т.е. нужно дефолтное значение.

Comment: DTO - это только шаблон для данных, не более. Не нужно валидировать в нём ничего. Данные Вам следует валидировать на входе, а не на выходе, поэтому создавайте отдельный класс валидации.

Answer (score 0):

В DTO(Data transfer object) валидация данных возможна, но только в рамках возможных договоренностей и бизнес моделей.

Ниже пример DTO где есть 2 сервиса передачи данных для валидации, например проверка паспорта и оценка недвижимости.

Допустим есть требования от внешних поставщиков данных:
Требования по проверке паспорта - если нет 14 лет, присылать нули
Требования по проверке машин: Машины старше 5 лет оценке не подлежат
Требования по проверке недвижимости: оцениваются только капитальные строения.

Предположим, что это наша модель данных, которую мы получаем(из БД, от внешнего сервиса, не важно). При получении мы ее отвалидировали. Т.е. данные валидны, достаточны и с ними можно работать!

```
const clientData = {
  name: 'Андрей',
  surname: 'Оверфлов',
  patronymic: 'Русович',
  age: '30',
  passSeries: '9876',
  passNum: '123456',
  eyeColor: 'red',
  numOfCars: 1,
  cars: [{
    age: 4,
    cost: 1,
  }],
  numOfBuilds: 1,
  builds: [
    {
      type: 'home',
      metrics: 100,
      cost: 100
    },
    {
      type: 'village',
      metrics: 1000,
      cost: 3
    }
  ]
}
// Создаем DTO для взаимодействия с сервисами. Сервисы могут быть как внутренние, так и внешние.

class AgeControl {
  constructor(data) {
    this.passSeries = data.age >= 14 ? data.passSeries : '0000';
    this.passNum = data.age >= 14 ? data.passNum : '000000';
  }
}

class PassControl extends AgeControl {
  constructor(data) {
    super(data)
    this.name = data.name;
    this.surname = data.surname;
    this.patronymic = data.patronymic;
  }
}

class Cars {
  constructor(data) {
    this.cars = data.filter(item => item.age <= 5);
  }
}

class Buildings {
  constructor(data) {
    this.buildung = data.filter(item => item.type === 'home');
  }
}

class Asset {
  constructor(data) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.surname = data.surname;
    this.patronymic = data.patronymic;
    this.cars = data.numOfCars ? new Cars(data.cars).cars : []
    this.buildings = data.numOfBuilds ? new Buildings(data.builds).buildung : [];
  }
}

// Какие то методы, которые передают данные во внешние сервисы
sendTo.checkPassport(new PassControl(clientData));
sendTo.validAsset(new Asset(clientData));
```

Как можно видеть, валидация данных есть, но она идет от бизнес логики и требований "внешних" сервисов.

Хотя это может противоречить первоначальной концепции, изложенной автором.

Как понимаю я, концепция нам говорит о том, что если есть возможность в одном вызове передать 100 объектов, то лучше их сагрегировать и передать в одном вызове, чем выполнять 100 вызовов. т.е. уменьшить количество сетевых запросов путем максимальной агрегации данных в одном запросе.